# EBADF (Bad file number) while loading subsampled version of image using getFileDescriptor

Tags: android, multithreading, android-asynctask, android-contentprovider, file-descriptor

I trying to execute below code using AsyncTask in single background thread. it gives **Bad File Number** .
after searching it on google i found that more then one thread try to access or open following file at same time but in my scenario only one background thread is running using asynctask . and below decodeBitmapFromDescriptor method is define in SinglTone Class.

```
public Bitmap decodeBitmapFromDescriptor(Uri data, int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws FileNotFoundException {

        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor= mContext.getContentResolver().
                        openFileDescriptor(data, "r").getFileDescriptor();

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);

        // it returns null don't know why ?? it works on api level 21
        if(bmp==null){
            bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
        }
        return bmp;
    }
```

following is the stacktrace of error.

> java.io.IOException: read failed: EBADF (Bad file number) 05-13
>   11:16:04.652  17881-19663/com.espec.bosleo.espec W/System.err﹕ at
>   libcore.io.IoBridge.read(IoBridge.java:442) 05-13 11:16:04.652 
>   17881-19663/com.espec.bosleo.espec W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.io.FileInputStream.read(FileInputStream.java:179) 05-13
>   11:16:04.652  17881-19663/com.espec.bosleo.espec W/System.err﹕ at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fillbuf(BufferedInputStream.java:168)
>   05-13 11:16:04.652  17881-19663/com.espec.bosleo.espec W/System.err﹕
>   at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:309)
>   05-13 11:16:04.652  17881-19663/com.espec.bosleo.espec W/System.err﹕
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
>   05-13 11:16:04.652  17881-19663/com.espec.bosleo.espec W/System.err﹕
>   at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:527)
>   05-13 11:16:04.652  17881-19663/com.espec.bosleo.espec W/System.err﹕
>   at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:626)
>   05-13 11:16:04.652  17881-19663/com.espec.bosleo.espec W/System.err﹕
>   at
>   android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(BitmapFactory.java:644)
>   ..................................

*Note : above code working properly on Lollipop version API21*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just done with it.
forget to close ParcelFileDescriptor.

```
public Bitmap decodeBitmapFromDescriptor(Uri data,
                                         int reqWidth, int reqHeight) throws IOException {

        ParcelFileDescriptor ParcelFileDescriptor= mContext.getContentResolver().
                        openFileDescriptor(data, "r");
        FileDescriptor fileDescriptor=ParcelFileDescriptor.getFileDescriptor();

        // First decode with inJustDecodeBounds=true to check dimensions
        final BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;

        BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);

        // Calculate inSampleSize
        options.inSampleSize = calculateInSampleSize(options, reqWidth, reqHeight);

        // Decode bitmap with inSampleSize set
        options.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
        Bitmap bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor, null, options);
        // Here is the solution of my problem
        ParcelFileDescriptor.close();
        fileDescriptor=null;
//        if(bmp==null){
//            bmp=BitmapFactory.decodeFileDescriptor(fileDescriptor);
//        }
        return bmp;
    }
```